# Unable to understand parallel resisitors

Tags: resistors, circuits

In the circuit attached in the image,I am unable to understand why R1,R2,R3,R4,R5 are not in parallel even though different current flows through them, any help would be appreciated [image]

Comment: "*"even though different current flows through*" if this is your definition what things in parallel are, then consider that the wire in one circuit also has a different current flowing through it than the wire in a completely different circuit. Obviously not in parallel. The definition is overly broad so as to be useless. Things are in parallel when the voltage across them is same.

Comment: How do I know if the voltage across them is the same?

Comment: Do they share the same node on both sides? If yes, parallel. If no, not parallel.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood it very well why R1 and R3 are  are not in parallel.

Comment: If 4 resistors are connected in a square pattern, how do I find the total resistance then?

Comment: That's a different question so ask a new one. You'll need to specify at which nodes the resistance is being measured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, they are in parallel *if and only if* their respective terminals are tied together *and nothing else is in the way*. There is a more formal definition using topology but it's not very useful.

R1 is in parallel with R2: pin A of R1 is directly tied to pin A of R2, pin B of R1 is directly tied to pin B of R2;

R1 is *not* in parallel with R3: between pin A of R1 and pin A of R3 there is a battery and the K thingy (no idea of what that symbol mean).

Even if we reorder the circuit like this (Kirchoff says we can do it due to current law)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flZsze.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is still *not* in parallel with R3 since even if one terminal is in common between them, between the other there still is the source and ammeter

Comment: If I understood it correctly R1 is in parallel with R2 and R3,R4 and R5 are in parallel

Comment: Exactly, the parallel groups are then in series

Answer (score 2):

There are two parallel circuits in series with each other. One parallel circuit is made up of R1 and R2, the other parallel circuit is R3,R4 and R5. So, the circuit equation for total resistance would be:

(1/(1/R1+1/R2)) + (1/(1/R3+1/R4+1/R5))